# Plot bar chart based on column blocks

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have dataset (Sample dataset)

```
     Contract Sections  A001_Average_By_Block  A002_Average_By_Block
0     O.U20       O1                  0.005               0.002915
1     O.Z20       O1                  0.005               0.002915
2     O.H21       O1                  0.005               0.002915
3     O.M21       O1                  0.005               0.002915
4     O.U21       O2                  0.005               0.004443
5     O.Z21       O2                  0.005               0.004443
6     O.H22       O2                  0.005               0.004443
7     O.M22       O2                  0.005               0.004443
8    S3.U20       S3                  0.500               0.250000
9    S3.Z20       S3                  0.500               0.250000
10   S6.M26       S6                    NaN               3.875000
11   S6.U26       S6                    NaN               3.875000
12   S6.Z26       S6                    NaN               3.875000
13   S6.H27       S6                    NaN               3.875000
14   S9.U26       S9                    NaN               5.250000
15   S9.Z26       S9                    NaN               5.250000
16   F3.U26       F3                  2.000                    NaN
17   F3.Z26       F3                  2.000                    NaN
18   F3.H27       F3                  2.000                    NaN
19   F6.H26       F6                    NaN              10.833333
20   F6.M26       F6                    NaN              10.833333
21   F6.U26       F6                    NaN              10.833333
22   F9.U20       F9                  1.500               1.000000
```

I'm trying to construct a bar chart plot of `A001_Average_By_Block` and `A002_Average_By_Block`

I can construct the plot based on Contract, a separate chart for each of the Contract products in the data e.g, the chart for O, S, F (and more Contracts in original dataset), this one is just for O.

[image]

using the code (please let me know if there is a better way of doing it)

```
  df_O = df[df['Contract'].str.contains('O')]
ax = df_O[['A001','A002']].plot(kind='bar', title ="Outrights - All data points", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xticklabels(df_O['Contract'], rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

Now what I'm trying to do is create a separate bar chart on the basis of the `Section` column. In my case 'O.U20 - O.M21' belongs to O1 block and all of them have the same '`A001_Average_By_Block`' value (same in the case of `A002_Average_By_Block`. Using the same above code I get something like

￼￼￼[image]

which is obviously not correct as I want only O1 and O2 in the xticker labels and just two corresponding bars that compares the two mentioned column. I tried this code

```
pd.value_counts(df_O['Sections']).plot.bar()
```

but it is just counting the number of times O1 and O2 occurs. What I want is that if there are 8 blocks of O (sample data shows just two blocks O1, O2) I can get a graph that looks something like this

[image]

How can I achieve the desired charts?  Basically the structure of data looks something like this (Hopefully this makes sense now)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The dataframe needs to be reshaped depending on the what needs to be plotted.
- Convert the data to long format with `.stack`
- Drop `Contract`
- Drop the duplicates
- The data value range is large, so if you don't use log scale on y, some values won't display.
- Dataframe `df` is the data in the question

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# dataframe to long format
dfl = df.set_index(['Contract', 'Sections']).stack().reset_index()

# drop
dfl.drop(columns=['Contract'], inplace=True)
dfl.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

# plot
sns.barplot('Sections', 0, data=dfl, hue='level_2')
plt.yscale('log')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, it works well, Just a little question, can I include specific columns instead of dropping all the columns? As I have columns other than Average columns and I have to drop them before making a graph

Comment: @hyeri Instead of dropping columns you can select the specific columns like `df[['cola', 'colb', 'colc']]`